# I am Using WordPress For website building facing issue with Images customization,

Tags: forum

I am currently facing with image customization on my WordPress website. Specifically, I have encountered a discrepancy where two images appear to be similar during customization, but upon previewing the final website, one of the images appears differently than expected.

I have carefully reviewed the image settings and ensured that they are consistent across both images. However, despite my efforts, the discrepancy persists.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCyos.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8PXE.png)

help me to Resolove the issue